# WSO2 ESB 7.1.0 Binary response is truncated to 375B

Tags: binary, wso2, binary-data, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have problem with binary response in WSO2 ESB 7.1.0 - it looks like the answer is truncated to 375B (body part - binary data).

This is fragment of my sequence - response build:

```
<payloadFactory description="Build Payload Response" media-type="xml">
  <format>
    <ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">BASE64_FILE_CONTENT</ns:binary>
  </format>
  <args/>
</payloadFactory>
<script language="js"><![CDATA[var binaryNode = mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstOMChild();  
  binaryNode.setBinary(true);]]></script>
<propertyGroup description="Set Content-Type">
  <property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
  <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
  <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/octet-stream"/>
  <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/pdf"/>
</propertyGroup>
<header description="Set Content-Disposition" name="Content-Disposition" scope="transport" value="attachment; filename=&quot;raport.pdf&quot;"/>
```

Of course in place BASE64_FILE_CONTENT I put real file content encoded in BASE64.
Mesasge formatter configuration (I use application/octeat-stream or application/pdf -> org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter with the same result):

```
<messageFormatters>
  <messageFormatter contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.formatters.XFormURLEncodedFormatter"/>
  <messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.MultipartFormDataFormatter"/>
  <messageFormatter contentType="application/xml" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"/>
  <messageFormatter contentType="text/xml" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
  <messageFormatter contentType="application/soap+xml" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
  <messageFormatter contentType="text/plain" class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"/>
  <messageFormatter contentType="application/json" class="org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
  <messageFormatter contentType="application/json/badgerfish" class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBadgerfishMessageFormatter"/>
  <messageFormatter contentType="text/javascript" class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/>
  <messageFormatter contentType="application/octet-stream" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
  <messageFormatter contentType="application/binary" class="org.apache.axis2.format.BinaryFormatter"/>
  <messageFormatter contentType="application/pdf" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
</messageFormatters>
```

I tryied with a few sample files and result was always the same - headers and the beggining of binary data looks good, but data is truncated on 375B:

[Postman screenshot - 375B for body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Etw.png)

Does this value (375B) come from any parameter? Can anyone suggest how to correctly return a file in WSO2 (as binary data in the response)?

Best regards

Marcin Orliński

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, funnily enough, the content is cut at the same byte. Took me two days, but I managed to resolve this.

The issue lies deep within WSO2, more specifically in Woodstox parser. Chances are, that you've created `XMLInputFactory.properties` in the root WSO2 directory with `javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing=false` to enable CDATA usage in PayloadFactory mediator.

With coalescing disabled, Woodstox takes advantage of text buffering. This unfortunately results in multiple child text nodes. If you look at the source code for `org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter` at line 170 (in master branch at the time of writing), you can see, that only first text node is serialized as binary content.

```
OMNode node = contentEle.getFirstOMChild();
OMText binaryDataNode = (OMText) node;
DataHandler dh = (DataHandler) binaryDataNode.getDataHandler();
...
dh.writeTo(out);
```

[Here](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/configuring-woodstox-xml-parser-woodstox-specific-properties-1ce5030a5173) is a list of more Woodstox properties. This is the one relevant:

> P_MIN_TEXT_SEGMENT (default: 64): when NOT using “coalescing” mode, this setting defines smallest partial text segment (that is, part of one contiguous text segment) that may be reported — intention being to reduce likelihood of returning tiny segments while allowing parser to avoid having to buffer longer segments completely.
> Setting this value to Integer.MAX_VALUE will effectively prevent splitting of individual segments without forcing coalescing of adjacent segments, so that is one common override

So the solution is fortunately relatively simple, just add `com.ctc.wstx.minTextSegment=2147483647` to the `XMLInputFactory.properties`.